# Distribution of a perpetual integral of Browian motion

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

There exist some results concerning to the distribution of perpetual integral functionals of Brownian motion of the form $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda s}f(B_{s}) \mathrm{d}s$, where $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function,  $\{B_{s}:s\geq 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion and $\lambda>0$ is a constant?

Comment: Depends on $f$. Any specific situation in mind?

Comment: When $f(x)=\min\{e^{ax}.e^{bx}\}$, where $a,b$ are positve constants with $a\leq b$.

Comment: In the case $\lambda=0$, there are some classical results concerning to the finiteness of that random variable and its the exactly distribution.

Comment: ?? When lambda=0, with your function f, the integral is obviously infinite, no?

Comment: Yes, that is clear.

Comment: When $\lambda>0$ and $f$ is as above, any comment?

Comment: $f(x)=\min\{e^{ax},e^{bx}\}$